# angular finally clause not getting called on promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have a RestService which returns a promise on calling request. This in turn is called from a method defined in RestService and finally from a controller method as shown below. I assumed that finally clause will be called in the controller either in case of success or failure but it is not getting called. I am using angular 1.3.13.

```
var restService = {
'request': function(args) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({
            url: url,
            withCredentials: this.use_session,
            method: method.toUpperCase(),
            headers: headers,
            params: params,
            data: data,
            timeout: 20000
        })
        .success(angular.bind(this, function(data, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.resolve(data, status);
        }))
        .error(angular.bind(this, function(data, status, headers, config) {
    deferred.reject(data);
        }
   return deferred.promise;
}

'listAssignments': function(filters) {
  return this.request({
        'method': "GET",
        'url': "/assignments/",
        'params': filters
      });
}

}; // end restService object

 restService.listAssignments(filters)
  .then(function(data) {
    $log.debug("success " + data);  
  }, function(data) {
    $log.debug("error " + data);  
  })
  .finally(function() {
    $log.debug("In finally.... calling scrollHelper");
  });
```

Comment: you can return $http directly because $http returns a promise. Don't create another promise, what you are doing is called an anti pattern : https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns

Comment: Is your success or error function getting called ?

Comment: Yeah my success and error functions are working fine.

Comment: @ThibaudL: What if I want to modify the data being returned after a call from server? Would it still count as antipattern?

Comment: Is this all browsers? Keep in mind that in some IE you need to use `['finally']`

Comment: @DivKis01 you return the $http but you can keep your .success and .error in which you can manage your data

Comment: Otherwise try :  listAssignments().then().fin()    source : https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promisefinallycallback

Comment: @ThibaudL: Even after 'fixing' the anti pattern, my finally callback is not getting called. And on using .fin, it complains that .fin is not a function.

Comment: @ThibaudL: BTW I see this anti-pattern being used almost everywhere. Say for example http://jmdobry.github.io/angular-cache/ which is a angular cachefactory replacement and elsewhere too. It is surprising that it is so ubiquitous.

Comment: @DivKis01 I did it myself until a few weeks but once you see it it's obvious, you already have a promise why creating another one ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it working. For some reason if I set a finally handler on the $http, the finally handler in the chain does get called. i.e. it works if I have the following code:

```
var restService = {
'request': function(args) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({
            url: url,
            withCredentials: this.use_session,
            method: method.toUpperCase(),
            headers: headers,
            params: params,
            data: data,
            timeout: 20000
        })
        .success(angular.bind(this, function(data, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.resolve(data, status);
        }))
        .error(angular.bind(this, function(data, status, headers, config) {
           deferred.reject(data);
        })).finally(function() {
           // Just by adding a finally clause on $http, the finally
           // handler in the chain i.e. in the controller utilizing
           // the restService, does get called.
        });
   return deferred.promise;
}

'listAssignments': function(filters) {
  return this.request({
        'method': "GET",
        'url': "/assignments/",
        'params': filters
      });
}

}; // end restService object

 restService.listAssignments(filters)
  .then(function(data) {
    $log.debug("success " + data);  
  }, function(data) {
    $log.debug("error " + data);  
  })
  .finally(function() {
    $log.debug("In finally.... calling scrollHelper");
  });
```